# Hatcheck Experiment $n=2k$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm sure the famous hatcheck experiment is well known. However I stumbled upon an interesting question.

Consider the experiment with $n=2k$ hats, in other words an even number of hats.

Find the probability of $ A = \{h_i = i \text{ if } i  \text{ is even} \}$ and $B = \{h_i = i \text{ if } i  \text{ is even and } h_i \neq i \text{ if } i \text{ is  odd} \}$.

What is $P_A B$?

Comment: What does the notation $P_AB$ stand for?